# Cannot write to a file using open()

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement

This code always goes into the except section

```
to_add = "text to add"
try:
    with open ('text.txt','r') as txt:
        txt.write('text to add'+to_add')
        print("done")
    except:
        to_add== 0 or None or '' 
        print("unable to write to file")
```

Comment: There is an extra quote here `txt.write('text to add'+to_add')`. Remove the last one.

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: To write to a file use `open(file_name, 'w')` or append with `open(file_name, 'a')`. You've opened it in read mode using the `'r'` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open file as 'w' not 'r'

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as txt:
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple fixes required.

try with this snippet:

```
to_add = "text to add"
try:
  with open ('text.txt', 'w') as txt:    # change the mode to write 
      txt.write('text to add' + to_add)  # removing the last char '
  print("done")
except NameError:  
  print("unable to write to file")
```